# Error 404 ngix - GAE php - How to properly define subfolders in the handlers attributes of app.yaml file?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, handler, app.yaml

i have some problems with the app.yaml file definition. I have tried to deploy a simple application on GAE, but i always get a 404 error everytime i try to access my app at https://myapp.appspot.com/api/v1/validate:

Here the folder structure:

- app.yaml
- web

  - api

    - v1

      - validate

        - index.php

Here my app.yaml code:

```
  runtime: php
  env: flex

  runtime_config:
   document_root: web

  handlers:
  - url: /api/v1/validate/.*
    script: index.php
```

what did I do wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to successfully deploy a similar setup. Here are my changes:

Access URL: https://YourProject.appspot.com/api/v1/validate/index.php

In index.php modified line 20 as 
`require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';`

In app.yaml added handler as:

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
 document_root: web

handlers:
- url: /api/v1/authenticate
  script: /api/v1/authenticate/index.html

- url: /api/v1/userprofile
  script: /api/v1/userprofile/index.php
```

And its working just fine.

For this, I just followed the [Quickstart for PHP in the App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/quickstart) Documentation and modified the helloworld directory as

My folder structure its the exact same as you.

***Update***

After taking a look at your code I managed to deploy an app like with these settings

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
 document_root: web

handlers:
- url: /api/v1/authenticate
  script: /api/v1/authenticate/index.html

- url: /api/v1/userprofile
  script: /api/v1/userprofile/index.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

    include '../../utils.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = new Silex\Application();
    $app->get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
    });
    $app->get('/goodbye', function () {
    return 'Goodbye World';
    });
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    if (PHP_SAPI != 'cli') {
    $app->run();
    }
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    return $app;
?>
```

What I see is that you aren't handling the http request in a proper way. You can take a look at the index.php added above, if you replace one of your index.php codes with this code you will see that the yaml file will let you connect to your app at https://YOUR_APP.devshell.appspot.com/api/v1/userprofile/index.php

Comment: Hi Christian, thank you for the answer. I've done the suggested changes but it still doesn't work.

Here the app.yaml file and the index.php code screenshots: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e59f38091c2a70c03379dacb581f1f8020190906100302/958c4b

Comment: same 404 error? are you accesing with https://myapp.appspot.com/api/v1/validate or with https://myapp.appspot.com/api/v1/validate/index.php?

Comment: Also I noticed that in your question you stated /api/v1/validate/index.php as your route but actually in the pictures that you are sharing with me your route should be /api/v1/authenticate/index.php can you please double check this?

Comment: if i access to myapp.appspot.com/api/v1/authenticate (this is the right path and not the one with "validate" sorry) i get 404, otherwise if access to myapp.appspot.com/api/v1/authenticate/index.php i get 502 error,  i noticed that your app.yaml file has the attribute "static_files" but if i try to use this attribute instead of "script" the deploy fails with the error "Missing "upload" attribute for URL "/api/v1/authenticate"."

Comment: For the missing upload error you just need to add `upload: /api/v1/authenticate/index.html` under the static_files in the yaml file

Comment: It doesn't work, here my app.yaml

runtime: php
env: flex

runtime_config:
 document_root: web

handlers:
- url: /api/v1/authenticate
  static_files: /api/v1/authenticate/index.php
  upload: /api/v1/authenticate/index.php

- url: /api/v1/userprofile
  static_files: /api/v1/userprofile/index.php
  upload: /api/v1/userprofile/index.php

Comment: Ok I can see your problem. In the app.yaml please change the .php at the end of static_files and upload fot a .html

Comment: It doesn't work this way, i get 404 error: 
handlers:
- url: /api/v1/authenticate
  static_files: /api/v1/authenticate/index.html
  upload: /api/v1/authenticate/index.html

why *.html? there are no html file in my directory

Comment: Ok don't worry, please upload a reproducible example to a git folder and I will reproduce the exact case for you

Comment: Hi, I managed to deploy an App Engine with your GitHub repo but not with the code inside of the index.php, this means that the app.yaml file its properly set for the subfolders. What I see is that you aren't handling the Http calls in a proper way, as a recommendation I would suggest you to deploy your app replacing the index.php with the one that I just added to the update on the answer. You will be able to see a hello world with your subfolders setting and over this code, you can implement your changes.